# Reuse of a nested utility class

Tags: c#, encapsulation, access-rights

I was designing a class where I wanted the properties to be accessible in a complete form internally to the class but only in a sanitized form externally. My first solution was to implement two different `get`ers with different access rights:

```
public class MyClass
{   
   private Foo CompleteFoo { get; set; }
   public Foo SanitizedFoo => CompleteFoo.WithoutSensitiveInfo();
}
```

As my class grew, it ended up with a lot properties like this, and having to define these accessors for each value became tiresome and made the class harder to read. So I decided to introduce a nested helper class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private class SanitizedValue<T> where T : Sanitizable 
    {
        private T Complete { get; set; }
        public T Sanitized => T.WithoutSensitiveInfo();
    }

    public SanitizedValue<Foo> foo { get; }
}
```

Now `MyClass` itself has access to both the `Sanitized` and `Complete` values, but external users only have access to the `Sanitized` value.

The issue is that I find this `SanitizedValue` class to be a pretty useful utility, and something I might want to use in a variety of different classes in order to replicate the access-rights pattern. But because `SanitizedValue` has to be internal to `MyClass` in order to properly allow access to the `Complete` property, it seems like I would have to rewrite the `SanitizedValue` class for every parent that would want to use it.

Is there a strategy to avoid this duplication of the internal class?

Comment: The MVVM pattern requires a lot of Plumbing code for classes. In particular, every property must be given change Notification and possibly a relay call to the Model class (the nested class for you). If one group knows of a good way to encapsulate stuff without too much writing work, it is WPF/UWP developers.

Comment: I think a proper example with some fields would make more sense. Is Sanitized accessing internal variables of complete than how could you use it across multiple classes. 
What I could say is Sanitized has some rules (implemented as functions/prop) and it requires data that it will get from Complete. Sanitized should be independent of the class,  a generic class that just acts on data. How you pass the data is different topic ?

Comment: Does your new nested generic class even compile?

Comment: I was thinking the Decorator or Visitor patterns could be used here.

Comment: @Dan if you can provide a little more clarity on existing samples then someone might be able to provide you a prototype of class design.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to achieve here is to narrow public API to only that data, that should be accessible from outside, how about introducing public interface, that is used in property signature?

For example:

```cs
public class FooContainer
{
   private Foo _myFoo;
   public IFoo MyFoo => _myFoo;
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
   //This is visible in your public API
   public bool NonSensitiveFlag { get; private set; }
   public string NonSensitiveString { get; private set; }

   //This is not visible due to not being present in IFoo definition
   public string MySensitiveString { get; set; }
}

public interface IFoo
{
   bool NonSensitiveFlag { get; }
   string NonSensitiveString { get; }
}
```

This of course, only somehow solves the problem you had in the beginning, no the issue with `SanitizedValue<T>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to limit access via accessor instead of using a contract (interface).  It's much easier to limit the exposure of class properties, methods and fields by interface.

In this example, I not only limited `Person` via `IPerson` but also limited `Person.SSN` by exposing only `ISensitiveString` not `SensitiveString`

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ig9Hzw)

```cs
namespace One
{
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var person = Two.PersonFactory.Create("123-45-6789");
            Console.WriteLine(person.SSN.Value);
            // Console.WriteLine(person.SSN.RawValue); // 'ISensitiveString' does not contain a definition for 'RawValue' and no accessible extension method 'RawValue' accepting a first argument of type 'ISensitiveString' could be found
        }
    }
}

namespace Two
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    
    public static class PersonFactory
    {
        public static IPerson Create(string SSN)
        {
            var result = new Person();
            result.SSN.RawValue = SSN;
            
            Console.WriteLine(result.SSN.RawValue);
            Console.WriteLine(result.SSN.Value);
            
            return result;
        }
    }

    public interface IPerson 
    {
        ISensitiveString SSN { get; }
    }

    internal class Person : IPerson
    {
        ISensitiveString IPerson.SSN => SSN;

        public SensitiveString SSN { get; set; } = new SensitiveString();
    }

    public interface ISensitiveString
    {
        string Value { get; }
    }
    
    internal class SensitiveString : ISensitiveString
    {
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                string result;
                using (var sha512 = SHA512.Create())
                {
                    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RawValue);
                    var hash = sha512.ComputeHash(bytes);
                    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(128);
                    foreach (var b in hash)
                        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
                    result = sb.ToString();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        
        public string RawValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Ouput

> 123-45-6789
> FBE47783B1D59D46DD437BDE9236A5404A8E8394F76E1C31D8421FD604D9BD1DF0C52DF5E5FD9C41879659D46C9A839266144E6C5FCAA678653290ED9EFFAEA7
>
> FBE47783B1D59D46DD437BDE9236A5404A8E8394F76E1C31D8421FD604D9BD1DF0C52DF5E5FD9C41879659D46C9A839266144E6C5FCAA678653290ED9EFFAEA7